# How to create ActiveRecord query for this MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

I got MySQL query, how I can write this with ActiveRecord?

```
SELECT *
FROM `sel_posts`
WHERE `login_id` = 22 OR 23 OR 24 ... (this ids from array $ifollow)
ORDER BY `datetime` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's better replace `OR` with `IN` in `WHERE` part.

Assuming the model is named `SelPost`, here is how you can do it with `ActiveQuery`:

```
$models = SelPost::find()
    ->where(['login_id' => $ifollow])
    ->orderBy(['datetime' => SORT_DESC])
    ->limit(20)
    ->all();
```

`where` is smart enough to automatically add `in` operator in case of `$ifollow` being array.

**Official documentation:**

- [SQL IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)
- [Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html)
- [ActiveQuery](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html)